# Which is the easiest way to reset the mysql root password?

Tags: password, mysql

In the past there has been `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql reset-password`, (1) is manually restarting and setting the password with an sql command again required? (2)

(1) http://www.ubuntugeek.com/reset-the-root-password-on-mysql.html
(2) http://www.howtoforge.com/reset-forgotten-mysql-root-password

Comment: second link look like the way to go

Answer (score 6):

There's also an administrative user equivalent to root: debian-sys-maint. You can use this account to reset root's password. You can find its password in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf

Answer (score 5):

You could create a sql file say `/root/mysql.reset.sql` with the content:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('yourpassword') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And just call:

```
mysqld_safe --init-file=/root/mysql.reset.sql
```

Will be very helpful if you are in a habit of forgetting passwords often.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

you can use tab complete after `mysql-server-` if you're using a different version of mysql.

Answer (score 1):

tumbleweed's answer was the only one that helped me.  I was dealing with what could possibly have been a corrupted root user and none of the standard methods resolved the issue of not being able to log in as root.

Using the debian-sys-maint user, I was able to finally log into MySQL with escalated privileges and even then resetting the root password did not work.

However, I was able to recreate the root user:

```
DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<newpassword>';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

... and finally all was right with the world again!

I hope that helps a desperate soul out there...

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop the MySQL Server.

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
   ```
2. Start the mysqld configuration.

   ```
   sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
   ```
3. Login to MySQL as root.

   ```
   mysql -u root mysql
   ```
4. Replace YOURNEWPASSWORD with your new password!

   ```
   UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
2. `sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld/`
3. `sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld/`
4. `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`
5. `sudo mysql -u root`
6. `use mysql;`
7. `update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("New_Passwore_Here") where User='root';`
8. `flush privileges;`
9. `exit;`
10. `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
11. `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  Your answer might be correct but should be documented: it is not recommended to just give an instruction list.  In this case, I do not see a problem but, in general, if a user mistypes something, it could lead to unwanted results.  You also use 'sudo' even when it is not necessary (`sudo mysql...`) which is potentially dangerous.