# iRedMail - Entered wrong mysql root password during install - how do I fix it?

Tags: mysql, email, postfix

I just tried to install iRedMail on Ubuntu 16.04 following this tutorial: https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/ubuntu-16-04-iredmail-server-installation

However, I entered the wrong root password during installation and could see a lot mysql errors saying the password was incorrect.

Is there any way I can redo this process? I also noticed that mail.domain.com/iredmail/ returned a 404 not found, but mail.domain.com/mail showed Roundcube but with this text

"DATABASE ERROR: CONNECTION FAILED!

Unable to connect to the database!
Please contact your server-administrator."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the easiest way to reset the mysql root password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89895/which-is-the-easiest-way-to-reset-the-mysql-root-password)

Comment: I don't want to reset the mysql root password

Comment: re run the command with the proper password

Comment: I would try to re run the install script again and enter the correct password.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't try to recreate the databases, it skipped all the operations after I was done with the blue pop up window.

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-empty-mysql-database/

Answer (score -1):

Re-run the install script again with the proper password.

Edit: The install script needs to be run with

```
sudo ./iRedMail.sh
```

Comment: I did that, but it didn't recreate the needed databases. It skipped pretty much all.

Comment: re-run the install script with sudo